# For what values of $n$ is it possible to divide into three piles of equal weight?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For $n \in \mathbb{N},n \geq 3$ we consider $n$ weights where the $k^{th}$ weight has a weight of precisely $k$ grams. For what values of $n$ is it possible to divide into three piles of equal weight?

**My work**

It is obvious that $\sum_{i=1}^n i= n(n+1)/2$ should divide $3$. This means $n\equiv 0,2 \pmod 3$.

But how do I show this for all such numbers?
Eg. $n=5 \Rightarrow \{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{5\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition, on seeing this problem, is as follows:

- there are a very large number of ways to divide the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ into three piles;
- there aren't that many possible different sums;
- so it should be possible to get the sums we want, unless there's some obvious reason that we can't, like divisibility.

Now I observe that if I have six consecutive integers $k, k + 1, k + 2, k + 3, k + 4, k + 5$, then I can break them up into three pairs each summing to $2k + 5$:

$$ 2k + 5 = (k + 5) + k  = (k + 4) + (k + 1 ) = (k + 3) + (k + 2). $$

So if I can divide the set $\{ 1 , 2, \ldots, n \}$ into three sets of equal weight, then I can do so for $n + 6, n + 12, \ldots$.  The hard part now is finding solutions for enough small values of $n$.

As you've observed it's doable for $n = 5$, with the partition $\{1, 4 \}, \{2, 3\}, \{ 5 \}$.  You can then add 6 and 11 to one part, 7 and 10 to a second, and 8 and 9 to a third (in any order) to get a solution for $n = 11$.

Can you find solutions for $n = 6, 8, 9$?

Comment: Your observation that among 6 numbers we have three partitions is useful. But how I do I proof the general result. For $n=6 \Rightarrow \{1,6\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\}$. For $n=8 \Rightarrow \{11,8,3\},\{10,7,4,1\},\{9,6,5,2\}$. For $n=9$ just consider $3$ rows or cols of a magic square.

Comment: Thanks man. Strong induction completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=9 \Rightarrow \{9,6\},\{8,7\},\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

I did this by folowing a simple algorithm :

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (verifying the condition) we consider the set $A =\{1,2,...,n\}$

Let $S_1 ,S_2, S_3$ be the three subsets of A we're looking for.

We use the notation :  $sum(S)= \sum_{i\in S}i$

Then we proceed like this for the two first sets $S_1,S_2$ :

- if $sum(S_i)<{n\over3} $ :
- - if $sum(S_i)+max(A)<{n\over3}$ :
- - - We move $max(A)$ from $A$ into $S_i$
- - else :
- - - We move ${n\over 3} - sum(S_i)$ from $A$ into $S_i$

Then we will have $S_3 = A$ ( remember each time we added an element to a previous set we deleted it from A )

I hope this helps =)

Comment: Nice algorithm. I think it works, but how do I justify that it works?

Comment: It works because of the way we construct the sets.

Comment: Please note that this is a proof question.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to edit but reach the 5 minutes edit delay.
We 'build' $S_1$ using the biggest 'building blocks' first so once $S_1$ is taken care of, we know we didn't 'wasted' any blocks ( an example of a waste would be using $5$ and $6$ instead of $11$ ).
I know this is far from rigourous but that's the best I can offer with my limited knowledge.